# Detecting if args[0] is null or is not a text file

Tags: java, exception, args

Can someone take a look at the code below and tell me why it isn't displaying an error message if args[0] is empty?  The program works fine if the file entered is a duplicate, displaying the file already exists message.  Java is throwing an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error on me.  I've tried adding that exception to the code as well but nothing is picking it up.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class inputTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    if(args.length() == 0){
    System.out.println("Please enter a correct text file name!");
    System.exit(1);
    }
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File(args[0]);
    if (file.exists()){
        System.out.println("This file already exists!"); // If file exists, throw exception
        System.exit(1);
    }
    // Create a file    
    java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file);

    }
}
```

Also, is there a way to ensure the file being entered at the command prompt is of .txt variety?

Comment: How are you invoking this to get args[0] as an empty string?

Comment: `args[0]` cannot be `null`. It can either throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` or actually contain something.

Comment: @Sotirios It is throwing an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and I cannot figure out how to catch it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will give comilation problem

`Cannot invoke length() on the array type String[]`

change to

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(args.length == 0){
        System.out.println("Please enter a correct text file name!");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File(args[0]);
    if (file.exists()){
        System.out.println("This file already exists!"); // If file exists, throw exception
        System.exit(1);
    }
    // Create a file    

    java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file);
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 is what I get when I use the code above.  I tried adding ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException to my throws line, still nothing.

Comment: @ch4dr0x use `args.length==0` then control will not go to the line where this exception is coming if size is 0

Comment: this is what I currently have: `public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
                java.io.File file = new java.io.File(args[0]);
                if(args.length == 0){
                System.out.println("Proper Usage is: java program filename");
                System.exit(0);
                }`

Comment: @ch4dr0x see the out put i just added to answer

Comment: Question, when you put the file in the "try" block, it isolates it from the rest of my code.  I have very little experience using try/catch, but if I have "output.println" code, would I put that all in the try block?  I am still getting this darn ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.  This is blowing my mind.

Comment: @ch4dr0x How Your code compiling with `IOException` thrown .Just Updated the answer in your way replace your main method with mine that i just updated in answer

Comment: I have no idea what I did differently but I completely deleted my code and started over with your post as a guideline.  Works like a charm!  Thank you so much!!

Comment: DONE!  :)  Now I just need to figure out how to only accept text files! LOL.  Thank you so much, I can't thank you enough!!

Comment: @ch4dr0x use `fileName.split(".")` function with file name then compare the arr[1].equals("txt")

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Apache Commons [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html) isEmpty() to test for emptiness of the Array without worrying about dealing with null array vs. empty array.

You can also use Apache Commons IO [FilenameUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html) getExtension() to get the extension of the file.

Though this won't help you master the concepts of Java, you may now become familiar with one of main sets of libraries used by Java devs, and with how to add libraries to your project.